# Getting HTTP response from a particular server behind NGINX

Tags: c#, http, nginx, tcp

Wanted to see if there is any way we could force NGINX to serve our request from one particular server behind it.

I am querying an NGINX server, and I get responses from two different servers. I can tell this by looking at the 'Server' header on the response. One server is consistently slower than the other in giving the data. is there any way I can make NGINX deliver content from the faster server ?

Even if you can point me in a direction - this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this several ways, you can either create an [upstream pool](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) and pass requests to it, or you can do it with [location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) block. Nginx also provides some [load balancer strategies](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html) to help with situations like yours.

Using upstream:

```
upstream backend {
    server 192.168.0.10; # Fast server
    server 192.168.0.11; # Slow server
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

Using location blocks:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.10;
    }
}
```

**Load balancing strategies**

Least connections - use the server with the least active sessions:

```
upstream backend {
    least_conn;
    server 192.168.0.10; # Fast server
    server 192.168.0.11; # Slow server
}
```

Session persistence - route the same user to the same backend for each request:

```
upstream backend {
    ip_hash;
    server 192.168.0.10; # Fast server
    server 192.168.0.11; # Slow server
}
```

Weighted balancing - send more requests to one server than another:

```
upstream backend {
    server 192.168.0.10 weight=3; # Fast server
    server 192.168.0.11; # Slow server
}
```

This strategy will cause the fast server to serve 3 requests for every request the slow server serves.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am trying to do this from the client side. I have no access to the Nginx server itself. Will you suggest any strategies to which I can query an Nginx so that my request will get forwarded to the faster server. I have seen some suggestions as to send null parameters, to use no cache headers etc but none seem to work. But yeah .. I am trying to do this from the client side.

Comment: It’s difficult just from the client side, there is little you can do since the balancing strategy is decided on the server side.